# .net framework 3.5 installation error code 0x800f0950 in windows server 2019

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, .net-3.5

[image]

hi friends any know how to fix windows server 2019 .net frameworks 3.5 installing error the error code is  0x800f0950

Comment: Same problem on Windows10 Home

Answer (score 3):

I had to use the hammer :(

1. Go to [Windows Insider Program](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewadvanced) and download a copy of Windows 10
2. Right click on the .iso file and select "Mount"

[image]

3. Check the letter of the driver that was mounted (Normally is `D:` but can be somethign else on your computer)
4. Now open an Administrator CMD Terminal and type:

   **Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess**

Set `D:` or whatever letter according to the letter where your .ISO was mounted

[image]

Comment: This worked for me also using a Windows Server 2019 ISO, using the exact same command

Comment: Thank you @Francesco Mantovani